# What's the normal line when partial derivative with respect to $x = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, tangent-line

So I know the equation of a normal line is: $$\frac{x-a}{f_1(a,b)}=\frac{y-b}{f_2(a,b)}=\frac{z-f(a,b)}{-1}$$. But in my textbook there is a litle note that says "with suitable modifications if either $f_1(a,b)=0$ or $f_2(a,b)=0$". Funny that they forget what that modification would look like. Now I have a problem where $f_1=0$, and don't know what to do. I searched for this topic, but frankly the given formula we use is apparantly not so common. Anyhow If someone would know the modification. It would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? If $f_1=0$ the normal line is $(a,b,f(a,b))+\lambda(0,f_2,-1)$. The denominators are the d-ratios of the vector parallel to the line.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply, but I'm actually looking for a modification of the formula above for the special case when $f_1=0$ or $f_2=0$

Comment: You can use the other form which I mentioned: position vector of a point on the normal line is $(x,y,z)=(a,b,f(a,b))+\lambda(f_x(a,b),f_y(a,b),-1)$. Personally, I don't see an issue in your current form even when $f_1=0$: I treat $\frac{x-a}{f_1}$ not as actual division but more of a notation where the denominator gives the $x$ component of the vector parallel to the line, which may be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a surface defined by $z=f(x,y)$ and a point $P(a,b, f(a,b))$ in that surface.

The plane tangent to the surface at point P is given by:

$z= f(a,b)+ \frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(a,b)(x-a)+ \frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(a,b)(y-a)$

Let's write it like

$f(a,b)+ \frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(a,b)(x-a)+ \frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(a,b)(y-a) -z =0$

Now compare with a generic plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$

We see that $A=\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(a,b)\;\;$ and $\;\;B=\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(a,b)\;\;$ and $\;\;C=-1$

We know that $(A,B,C)$ are the components of a vector perpendicular to the plane. So it's the normal to the surface in that point P.

Defining a line in 3D is better done in parametrics. So our normal is:

$x=a+At$

$y=b+Bt$

$z=f(a,b)-t$

If you eliminate "t" in these parametrics you arrive to your original expression

$\frac{x-a}{A}=\frac{y-b}{B}=\frac{z-f(a,b)}{-1}$

Notice that you can avoid division by zero:
$B(x-a)=A(y-b)$

Now, if $A=\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(a,b)=0$ then the first parametric is just $x=a$, but you can still use the other expression $\frac{y-b}{B}=\frac{z-f(a,b)}{-1}\;\;$ or without denominators $\;\;y-b=B(f(a,b)-z)$

Answer (score 0):

We are talking of the *normal* line, not the "tangent" line. Talking of surfaces we have tangent planes not tangent lines.

The general equation of the normal is
$$n:(x_0,y_0,z_0)+t (f'_{x_0},f'_{y_0},f'_{z_0})$$

Comment: Thank you my mistake I've eddited it. Now for you answer, I don't quite understand the equation right away. I really appreciate you helping me. But I am actually looking for a modification of the formula above. Still, thank you very much

Comment: Send the actual surface and the point and I'll help you @TheCreator